# Install USB wireless adapter tp-link tl-wn8200nd in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

This adapter sports the chipset Realtek rtl8192eu. How do I install the driver for this chipset?

Comment: Hey there!!! I liked your spirit of sharing knowledge. But since this site works on Q&A format, I'd encourage you to please reformat the post to make more like a question and post the steps to install drivers as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Run the following commands to install the driver located at https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux:

```
sudo apt -y install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git

git clone https://github.com/clnhub/rtl8192eu-linux

cd rtl8192eu-linux

./install_wifi.sh
```

Comment: It works for me with a TP-Link TL-WN8200ND on Ubuntu 20.04